Does $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sqrt{-x}$ exist?
Does $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sqrt{-x}$ exist?
I tried reading again and again the theory, and asking to people, even i ask to some AIs, and I don't get it.
If the limit approaches to $0$ from the left, it supposed to be $-0,000000001$ or something like that; but if that is right, when I do the substitution it shouldn't be:
$\sqrt{-(-0,000000001)} = \sqrt{0,000000001}$?, or what am I doing wrong?

You don't care about the limit from the right here, since you want the limit as $x \to 0^-$, i.e. the limit from the left. When you approach zero from the left, note that you will have, for instance, $x=-0.1$, so the function value is $\sqrt{-(-0.1)} = \sqrt{0.1}$

Yes, and it's the same as $\lim_{t\to 0^+}\sqrt{t}$ by substitution $t = -x$.

Your equation $\sqrt{-(-0,000000001)} = \sqrt{0,000000001}$ is perfectly correct. Why do you think you did something wrong?

Okay, I got it, so it exists?, I mean if the sqrt is positive it could exist, right?

By definition  $a^{-}$ means you are taking it from the LEFT and you are not taking it from the right.    So $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{-x}$ doe not exist because the limit from the right does not exist even though from the left it does.  And $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{-x}$ does not exist because the limit from the right doesn't exist and we don't care about the left.  And $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\sqrt{-x}$ does exist because the left limit does and we don't give a flying frigate in a jelly donut what the right limit does or does not do.

Okay, fnlly I got it at all. Thx so much.

By definition  the $a^-$ means from the left.  We simply do not care what happens to the right.  And $a^+$ means from the right and we don't care what happens on the left.  And $a$ means we care about both and hope they agree.
So $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\sqrt{-x}$ means $x <0$ and we just plain do not care about what happens when $x$ is positive.

So $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\sqrt{-x}$ does exist and is equal to $0$.  For all very small $x$ where $x < 0$ we have $\sqrt{-x}\to 0$ as $x\to 0^-$.  We do not care about very small positive $x$.  We only have to consider $x < 0$.
$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{-x}$ does not exist because even though $\sqrt{-x}\to 0$ for very small negative $x$, $\sqrt{-x}$ is not defined for very small positive $x$ and $x\to 0$ must consider both $x < 0$ and $x > 0$>
That's just what $a^{-}$ means.  We made up that notation precisely to describe left side limits when the right side limit does not matter.

Whether $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt x$ exists is a recent question too.

Because $x\rightarrow0^-$ we have that $x<0$ or $-x>0$. So this is another way of stating the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\sqrt{x}$ and you know the value of this limit.

Continuing on the comment of PrincessEev, which more or less solves the problem, you could actually carry on and use the definion of a limit of a function to answer your question.
Suppose $f:\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ is a function defined on the real line, and there are two real numbers $a$ and A.
One would say that the limit of $f$, as $x$ approaches $a$ from below, is $A$, if for every real $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a real $\delta > 0$ such that for all real $x$, $0 < a − x < \delta$ implies $|f(x) − A| < \varepsilon$.
Now, in your problem the probable limit is equal to zero, and the point on the $x$-axis at which it happens is $a=0$. Thus, the limit exists if:
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \,\exists \delta(\varepsilon)> 0, \,\forall x: 0 < −x < \delta \Rightarrow |\sqrt{-x}| < \varepsilon.
$$
Since $ −x < \delta$, it follows that $|\sqrt{-x}| < \sqrt{\delta}$, hence, taking $\delta = \varepsilon^2$ we prove the limit from below indeed exists and it's zero. The limit from above isn't defined because the square root of the negative variable isn't defined on a positive half-axis.
